# How to attach Authorization header when redirecting POST request?

Tags: http, security, redirect, jwt

We have a third party service that implemented single-sign-on on some route to it’s web-app.

In order to use this single-sign-on, we provided with a POST API, and we need to pass on that route some credentials- including an organization secret that we got from him (yes, we need to pass it in query params), and the user’s email address.

In order to not to expose credentials over the browser, we tried to mimic that request by creating our own backend endpoint, and return the same result as their enpoint (kind of a proxy) with redirection (status 307 with Location header) cause there API returns plain HTML.

It seems like when client send a post request with redirection he can’t add the authorization header (JWT) required by our backend to operate (backend return Authorization required). the request is been done to our server and the result is redirection to another server.
How can we bypass it? Or maybe we can secure it with different approach?

I know that the header is usually been removed for a good reason, who knows where I can be redirected to?
but can't I tell him somehow that I trust the redirection?

We tried to use phantom-form only to use from submit post. We tried to make our endpoint to be GET and making the redirection other way (react-router) but I think that natively js does not allow to attach Authorization header.
I thought it would be a common pattern, but I didn't find someone that talks about it exactly, since we are trying to query our backend and not some external redirection API.